# How can I work around json-encode error with key "t"

Tags: json

While working with JSON in Emacs Lisp, I got an error `json-encode-key: Bad JSON object key: t`. It made sense to me that the key was `"t"` but not necessarily *why*, or *what* I can do about it.

The following code sample reproduces this scenario:

```el
(let ((foo (json-read-from-string "{\"t\":42}")))
  (message "%s" foo)                  ; ((t . 42))
  (message "%s" (json-encode foo)))   ; json-encode-key: Bad JSON object key: t
```

How can I work around this, given that the JSON in question involves a key of `"t"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a well-known long-standing bug in `json.el` that has been fixed in the latest development version of Emacs (what will be released in the future as Emacs 28): https://bugs.gnu.org/42545

If you don't have access to the development version of Emacs, but have an Emacs 27 built with native JSON support (i.e. configured `--with-json` to link against the Jansson library, which is the default on systems where this library is available), then you can use the new native (and faster) functions in place of their `json.el` counterparts:

```el
(let ((foo (json-parse-string "{\"t\":42}" :object-type 'alist)))
  (message "%s" foo)                    ; ((t . 42))
  (message "%s" (json-serialize foo)))  ; {"t":42}
```

See [`(info "(elisp) Parsing JSON")`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Parsing-JSON.html) for more on this.

Otherwise, the only workaround for this bug is to avoid objects that have confusable keys such as the symbol `t`.  If you generate the data, then happy days: the fix is as simple as using a different object or key type that isn't as ambiguous, for example:

```el
(let* ((json-object-type 'hash-table)
       (foo (json-read-from-string "{\"t\":42}")))
  (message "%s" foo)                ; #s(hash-table ...)
  (message "%s" (json-encode foo))) ; {"t":42}

(let* ((json-key-type 'keyword)
       (foo (json-read-from-string "{\"t\":42}")))
  (message "%s" foo)                ; ((:t . 42))
  (message "%s" (json-encode foo))) ; {"t":42}
```

For more on this, have a read through the variables defined at the top of `M-x find-library RET json RET`.

If you don't generate the data, then you will probably need to sanitise it first.